# maven-archetype-plugin fails with ClassNotFoundException

Tags: maven, maven-plugin, apache-karaf

I'm trying to run maven-archetype-plugin, for instance

```
mvn org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-archetype-plugin:3.1.1:generate \
    -DarchetypeGroupId=org.apache.karaf.archetypes \
    -DarchetypeArtifactId=karaf-command-archetype \
    -DarchetypeVersion=4.2.6 \
    -DgroupId=examples.archetype \
    -DartifactId=my-test
```

but I get the following error:

```
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-archetype-plugin:3.1.1:generate 
  (default-cli) on project standalone-pom: Execution default-cli of goal
  org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-archetype-plugin:3.1.1:generate failed: 
  A required class was missing while executing 
  org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-archetype-plugin:3.1.1:generate: 
  org/apache/commons/lang/StringUtils
```

I tried with multiple archetypes (both open source and proprietary) but the outcome is always the error above. Also previous maven-archetype-plugin versions generate the same error.

My environment is

- Apache Maven 3.6.1
- Java version: 1.8.0_161
- MacOS

Do you know any solution or workaround to this problem (I already tried to erase the local repository folder)?

Comment: Please see https://nightofprompt.home.blog/2019/05/23/karaf-part1/. I hope it helps.

Answer (score 3):

the solution I found to work is adding commons-lang dependency to maven-archetype-plugin-3.1.2.pom

You can find maven-archetype-plugin-3.1.2.pom in your maven repo C:\Users\your_user\.m2\repository\org\apache\maven\plugins\maven-archetype-plugin\3.1.2\ maven-archetype-plugin-3.1.2.pom

Then add commons-lang to dependencies.

```
<dependency>
      <groupId>commons-lang</groupId>
      <artifactId>commons-lang</artifactId>
      <version>2.3</version>
</dependency>
```

Hope it helps.